# Why is this inequality False in C?

Tags: c, math, logical-operators, boolean-logic

Anyone can enlighten me on why `-5<-2<-1` returns `0` in C when I would expect it to return `1`(True)?

```
printf("%d", -5<-2<-1);
```

Comment: `-5<-2` is true, i.e. equal to 1. and `1 < -1` is false.

Comment: Why do you think it should be true? I assume because you expected `-5<-2<-1` to mean `(-5 < -2) && (-2 < -1)`. It does not. There are other languages where it does work that way, most notably Python (and it also will evaluate `-2` only once). But in C, `-5<-2<-1`, means `(-5 < -2) < -1`.

Comment: I think you are looking for `(-5 < -2) && (-2 < -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression

```
-5<-2<-1
```

is equivalent to

```
( -5<-2 ) < -1
```

because the operator < evaluates left to right.

As `-5` is less than `-2` then the value of the sub-exoression

```
( -5 < -2 )
```

is integer value `1`. So you have

```
1 < -1
```

and the result of this expression is 0 that is logical false.

From the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
> or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) **shall yield 1 if the
> specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type
> int**.

It seems you mean `- 5 < -2 && -2 < -1`